# Removing class from element after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

On an JS event, I add a class `moved` to an element.

How can I remove this class after 1 second?

I use Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout func:

```
setTimeout(function(){$('YouElement').removeClass('ClassName');},1000);
```